# Use "<>" or "!=", or does it really even matter

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

> Duplicate of: [Should I use != or <> for
>   not equal in TSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/723195/should-i-use-or-for-not-equal-in-tsql)

Within SQL Server's T-SQL should I use "<>" or "!=", or does it really even matter?

Comment: Duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/723195/should-i-use-or-for-not-equal-in-tsql/723203#723203

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say it comes down to your coding conventions. I personally like to use != as <> reminds me of dirty dirty VB and gives me a bad gut feeling. Plus I comprehend it better as it is exact to C#'s not equal operator.

Comment: Down votes with no reasoning? Gasp!

Answer (score 15):

I don't know SQLServer, but the SQL standard uses '<>', so follow the standard

Comment: Woah woah woah, which is the T-SQL standard? I always thought != was the T-SQL, and <> being the MS-way?

Comment: T-SQL is short for Transact-SQL, which is Microsoft's SQL Server implementation of SQL. T-SQL supports ANSI SQL and more.

Answer (score 6):

I believe that != is T-SQL specific (i.e. not standard SQL). So, you should use <> if there's any chance that you'll ever port your code to use a different DBMS.

Personally, I would use <> and forget about it.

Comment: != also works in MySQL, PostgreSQL and sqlite.

Answer (score 3):

Typical SQL usage in my experience is to use <>. I've never seen anyone use !=; I wasn't even aware that worked.

Answer (score 3):

!= isn't part of the standard, but it is part of T-SQL..

[SQL-92 standard](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt) , [T-SQL](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt)

Duplicate Post..

[Should I use != or <> for not equal in TSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/723195/should-i-use-or-for-not-equal-in-tsql/723203#723203)

Comment: these should go in the comments on the question so they're easier to see

Comment: Fair point, technically an exact duplicate as the answer would be the same.

Answer (score 2):

Use <> since most people are familiar with that, and whenever NULLs are possible, remember that NULL is not equal to NULL, so this is sometimes necessary:

```
ISNULL(MY_FIELD,0) <> ISNULL(MY_FIELD,0)
```

Comment: That would also equate a legit 0 to NULL, which may not be what you want. I always use (MY_FIELD1 <> MY_FIELD2 OR (MY_FIELD1 IS NULL AND MY_FIELD2 IS NULL)) but I'd be interested in seeing if someone else has a better way.

Comment: Yes, that's a great point.  The method you describe is more reliable.

Answer (score 1):

If you only use SQL Server, it doesn't matter. They are synonyms.

Answer (score 1):

they are identical.

Look [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190296(SQL.90).aspx).