# MYSQL syntax not evaluating not equal to in presence of NULL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having trouble with a mysql query.  I want to exclude values of 2.  So I thought I would do following:

```
table products

id | name     | backorder
-------------------
1  | product1 | NULL
2  | product2 | NULL
3  | product3 | 2

SELECT name from `products` p
WHERE backorder <> '2'
```

However, This is not giving the desired result of product1, product 2  It is giving an empty results table.

On the other hand if I use

```
SELECT name from `products` p
WHERE backorder = '2'
```

Then it produces: `product3`.  But I want to get those records where it is not equal to `2`.

Something is not working with the `<> '2'`.  Could it be that the `NULL` values are throwing it off?  Can anyone suggest a fix.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use the `NULL`-safe equality operator:  `WHERE NOT backorder <=> 2`

Answer (score 122, accepted):

use `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL` to compare `NULL` values because they are simply unknown.

```
SELECT name 
from   products p
WHERE  backorder IS NULL OR backorder <> 2
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/22a6a/3)
- [SQLFiddle Demo (*added some records*)](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e0e57/2)
- [Working with NULL Values](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/working-with-null.html)

Comment: That worked.  Will mark correct when SO allows me.  One question...some records have the value 1 in them.  To allow for case where value is NULL or 1 should I be able to do something like (backorder IS NULL OR backorder ='1') .  This is not working for me at the moment.

Comment: just to clarify, do you want to get both `NULL` and with value of `1`?

Comment: Yes, I want everything but value=2

Comment: so do you want to get all records except for `backorder = 2` right? then use this condition `backorder IS NULL OR backorder <> '2'` demonstrated here: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e0e57/2

Comment: Is the reason for having to do a separate NULL check because "Unknown value" could mean, "Well, it MIGHT be the value you're looking for, but I just don't know"?

Comment: it works but `IS NULL` is very slow for large data. is there any way  to make it faster

Answer (score 61):

### Use the [`<=>`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to) operator.

You can use:

```
SELECT `name` FROM `products` `p`
WHERE NOT `backorder` <=> '2'
```

or

```
SELECT `name` FROM `products` `p`
WHERE !(`backorder` <=> '2')
```

See this answer for more information about the `<=>` operator:

[What is this operator <=> in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21928508/293280)

Comment: Wow, this worked great. I didn't know `<=>` existed. I'm updating your answer with a bit more context...

Comment: Great! Thank you @JoshuaPinter

Answer (score 9):

We can use this also:

```
SELECT p.name 
FROM   products p
WHERE  COALESCE(backorder,1) <> 2
```

Comment: This breaks the ability to add indexes though

Answer (score -11):

Try this and see.

```
SELECT name from `products` p
WHERE backorder != '2'
```

Comment: Have you checked this?

Comment: No. This doesn't work. The operators `<>` and `!=` are equivalent. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2066987/using-the-correct-or-preferable-not-equal-operator-in-mysql