# Simple MySQL query :- What's wrong in it?

Tags: mysql

I am executing a MySQL query :-

```
SELECT * 
  FROM mytable 
 WHERE name LIKE '%D%' 
   AND id!='1'
```

It returns 1 result :-

```
name : Deepak
id: 2
username: NULL
```

It is working fine.

Problem is here.. :-

```
SELECT * 
  FROM mytable 
 WHERE name LIKE '%D%' 
   AND id!='1' 
   AND username!='d'
```

It returns 0 result , although username is null in mytable , but still it doesn't return the row of "Deepak" , as it returned in former query.

Please could you explain , why is it happening?

Comment: Because NULL is its own thing. It's neither equal nor not equal to anything else- not even NULL!

Comment: Ok, thank you very much..

Comment: @MichaelO. Nope. Although you could get away with <=>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16186674/mysql-syntax-not-evaluating-not-equal-to-in-presence-of-null), you need to check if the username "`is null`" or "`<> 'd'`".

```
SELECT * 
  FROM mytable 
 WHERE name LIKE '%D%' 
   AND id != '1' 
   AND (username IS NULL OR username != 'd')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't query a `NULL` since it represents no value. You should update your query to use `IS NULL` as follows:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM mytable 
 WHERE name LIKE '%D%' 
   AND id != 1 
   AND (username IS NULL OR username != 'd')
```

Answer (score 0):

`null` is not a value, it's the lack thereof. Think of it as an "unknown" value. Whenever you use it in an operator that expects a value (such as `=`), the result would be `null` (unknown). E.g. "What's the user's name? I don't know. Well, is it different than 'd'? Still don't know". If you want to handle `null`s, you'd have to do so explicitly with the `is` operator:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM mytable 
 WHERE name LIKE '%D%' 
   AND id!='1' 
   AND (username IS NULL OR username!='d')
```