# Problems with SUM in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table "Cabine" with fields "SBC750" (integer) and "Evaso" (tinyint)

The field Evaso can be 1, 0 or Null

I'm looking for the sum of all sbc750 where Evaso is NOT 1.

I tried with

```
select sum(sbc750) from cabine  where evaso<>1;
```

but the result is NULL: why???

If I use

```
select sum(sbc750) from cabine
```

I obtain 55 and if I use

```
select sum(sbc750) from cabine where evaso=1
```

I obtain 34!

So the results might be 21 and not Null. Please help me

Comment: What about SELECT SUM(sbc750) FROM cabine WHERE evaso>1 OR evaso<1

Comment: `select sum(sbc750) from cabine  where evaso IS NULL`

Comment: Probably related: [Is there any difference between IS NULL and =NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777230/is-there-any-difference-between-is-null-and-null#3777250)

Comment: I agree with Sari .. I have a feeling that with `<> 1` you are returning zero results .. Just try a `select * from cabine  where evaso<>1;` to test this theory ..

Comment: Yes with <>1 there is no results.. The Sari's suggestion doesn't work. The lad2025's one do.

Answer (score 1):

With the [`NULL-safe`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html) equality operator you should get the desired results:

```
select sum(sbc750) from cabine where not evaso<=>1;
```

Also see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16186674/mysql-syntax-not-evaluating-not-equal-to-in-presence-of-null) for reference.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT sum(sbc750) FROM cabine where evaso is null or evaso<>1;
```