# Deleting database existing record while asigning values from one row to other with unique values

Tags: mysql, database

**EDIT2: Solved** Thanks all for fast reply, appreciate ur help. Specially to Mr **Jeremy Smyth** for the working solution.

I'm fairly new to sql and cant find a solution to make an update query. I have the following table

Table: `order`

```
id | cid | pid 
1  | 1   |  a1 
2  | 1   |  a2
3  | 2   |  a2
4  | 2   |  a3
5  | 2   |  a4
```

I want the cid of 2 to become 1, BUT not updating rows which have same pid i.e(id.2 & id.3).
The result i want is:

```
id | cid | pid
1  | 1   |  a1
2  | 1   |  a2
3  | 2   |  a2
4  | '1' |  a3
5  | '1' |  a4
```

pseudo query example: UPDATE order SET cid=1 WHERE cid=2 AND 1.pid <> 2.pid;

**EDIT1:** not to confuse pid values with cid and id i changed them with 'a' in start. as suggested i'll not use order as table name.
On update I simply dont want duplicate pid for cid
Sorry for bad English.

Comment: What's `1.product_id` and `2.product_id`? It's not valid SQL syntax, and there are no `product_id` columns in your table (should that be `pid`?).

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. It's hard to tell quite what you want, since you gave such a tiny sample of data, and your explanation is not very good. "same pid" as what?

Comment: @Barmar the question is clear. same `pid` as `cid`.

Comment: @meze I don't think that's what he means. I suspect he means "same pid as another row with cid = 2"

Comment: Don't use reserved words for table names. IT WILL DRIVE YOU MAD!

Comment: @Barmar 1.product_id is for reference what is wanted it to be like to behave. The query is pseudo query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can only be done in multiple steps (i.e. not a single `UPDATE` statement) in MySQL, because of the following points

**Point 1**: To get a list of rows that do not have the same `pid` as other rows, you would need to do a query before your update. For example:

```
SELECT id FROM `order` 
WHERE pid NOT IN (
   SELECT pid FROM `order`
   GROUP BY pid
   HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
```

That'll give you the list of IDs that *don't* share a `pid` with other rows. However we have to deal with **Point 2**, from http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/subquery-restrictions.html:

> In general, you cannot modify a table and select from the same table in a subquery.

That means you can't use such a subquery in your `UPDATE` statement. You're going to have to use a staging table to store the `pid`s and `UPDATE` based on that set.

For example, the following code creates a temporary table called `badpids` that contains all `pid`s that appear multiple times in the `orders` table. Then, we execute the `UPDATE`, but only for rows that don't have a `pid` in the list of `badpids`:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE badpids (pid int);

INSERT INTO badpids
   SELECT pid FROM `order`
   GROUP BY pid
   HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;

UPDATE `order` SET cid = 1
WHERE cid= 2 
AND pid NOT IN (SELECT pid FROM badpids);
```

Comment: very much what i thought, but did not knew how to do. I haven't tried it. let me try and reply back. Yes

Comment: i'm so noob, ur asnwer is perfect, and thought me 1 thing i cant use select and update in same table. Besides ur code works as i wanted and u intended. There is one minor type semicolon missing in 2nd query which took me 7 tries to figure out why it was giving error. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: my friend also sugested me this query which works same as urs.     update `order` set `cid`='1' WHERE `cid`='2' and `pid` not in (select pid from (select distinct(`pid`) from `order` where cid='1') as temp_tbl)

Comment: how do i mark this as answered? Got it, the 'tick' check on left side.

Answer (score 2):

I hope I understood you right:

```
UPDATE `order`
   SET cid = 1 
 WHERE cid = 2 
   AND cid <> pid
```

What do you think?

**Please notice**: [ORDER](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/order-by-optimization.html) is a reserved word, [read more](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/order-by-optimization.html).

Comment: I would prefer using `<>` over `!=`. But that personal. [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2066987/using-the-correct-or-preferable-not-equal-operator-in-mysql) for more information.

Comment: @Mr.Bombastic ur code did not worked. it updates cid from 2 into 1 for every field. i dont want 3rd row to be updated bcoz that will create duplicate item for cid=1

Answer (score 1):

I think you need something like this.

```
UPDATE order SET cid=1 WHERE cid=2 AND cid <> pid;
```

Comment: ur code did not worked. it updates cid from 2 into 1 for every field. i dont want 3rd row to be updated bcoz that will create duplicate item for cid=1