# Mysql != vs <> comparisons

Tags: mysql, comparison

MySQL supports 2 different not equal operators, != and <>.

Is there any difference in functionality between the two where you would want to use 1 instead of the other in specific situations?

Comment: The only difference is that `<>` is the ANSI SQL standard.

Comment: I'd recommend <> simply to make your SQL more portable.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/723426/2097224

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are the same. Both are two Not Equal To operators. But != is not ISO standard.

**!=**
Tests whether one expression is not equal to another expression (a comparison operator). If either or both operands are NULL, NULL is returned. Functions the same as the <> (Not Equal To) comparison operator.

**<>**
Compares two expressions (a comparison operator). When you compare nonnull expressions, the result is TRUE if the left operand is not equal to the right operand; otherwise, the result is FALSE.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference in MySQL between the two, they both behave the same. However `<>` is standard SQL so if you get used to using that then you won't have any problems if you move to a RDBMS that doesn't support `!=`

Answer (score 0):

As Adriano said before, exactly the same, see documentation:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html

The question does show considerable lack of research.

Comment: Your final sentence is unnecessary.

Comment: It's 1 Google search straight to the developers documentation and it lists that both operators operate the same way. As Up_One mentioned in his resonse, != is not standard whilst many developers will be familiar with it, whereas <> is standard and widely implemented in just about every database system.

Comment: Which is something the documentation doesn't mention. I don't know about you, but I don't live in a world where documentation is always 100% complete either. Regardless, your rude comments add nothing to your answer. If you feel you must make them, then they belong in a comment...

Comment: That's fair enough, but documentation is supposed to be a starting point at the very least. Here's an answer to this question already: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2066987/using-the-correct-or-preferable-not-equal-operator-in-mysql and you already pointed it out... so...

Comment: The question states 'Is there any difference in functionality...' - the manual answers that exactly. Whether or not one is better in general is debatable and a matter of opinion.

Comment: @JustinMitchell I did look at the MySQL documentation before posting this question.  The reason I asked this querytion is because I saw some code that referenced != as 'not equals' and <> and 'basic not equals' and the documentation does not explicitly say those 2 operators function the same.  I assumed that the documentation would have mentioned if there was a functional difference between the two however it would not be the first time that type of assumption based on document was not correct.