# What is this symbol in an SQL query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
where _c1.name<>c2.name
```

I am confused with the symbol `<>`. Please explain its meaning.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Greater than and less than.

In other words not equal to aka `!=`.

To put it rather confusingly `!=` = `<>` , yes they can be used interchangeably.

Comment: Sure.You CAN - the author of the test you quote did chose not to.

Comment: @NoviceToDotNet see this previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/723195/should-i-use-or-for-not-equal-in-tsql

Answer (score 3):

It means "[not equal to](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa276877%28v=SQL.80%29.aspx)". It is an alternative to using `!=`. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa276846%28SQL.80%29.aspx) is a list of the operators used in SQL Server.

It comes from meaning `<` less than or `>` greater than. i.e. anything but equal.

Answer (score 3):

It means different. Your clause indicates that `_c1` and `c2` must not have the same `name` value.