# Are there any SQL dialets recommending to use != over <> for not equal?

Tags: sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should I use != or <> for not equal in TSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/723195/should-i-use-or-for-not-equal-in-tsql)

I see a number of questions using **!=** to express the not equal operator in SQL.

Working mostly with SQL-Server and Oracle I usually prefer **<>** .

Are there DBMS which do not support **<>** ?

**Edit:**

SQL-Server even supports these 2-character operators with an embedded blank in between. I think that is from old Sybase days. I think no other DBMS followed them in this respect. And when you have to migrate your query to another DBMS it just becomes an error. Better don't use it.

Comment: According to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/723195/should-i-use-or-for-not-equal-in-tsql `<>` is ANSI. I don't own a copy of the standard but if correct I guess the question should be the other way round. Edit: Bill Karwin's answer there answers this I think.

Comment: Thanks. Yes http://stackoverflow.com/questions/723195/should-i-use-or-for-not-equal-in-tsql/723426#723426 answers my question.

Comment: you should maybe delete this then, rather than having it closed...?

Comment: @gbn the other question is TSQL specific