# MySQL exclude row

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT id,x,y FROM `chars` WHERE `mapa`='1'
```

how can i exclude row when id='3'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT id,x,y FROM `chars` WHERE `mapa`='1' and id <> '3'
```

What is the data type  of `id` though? If numeric you would want to use

```
SELECT id,x,y FROM `chars` WHERE `mapa`='1' and id <> 3
```

In MySQL you can also use `!=` rather than `<>` but `<>` is ANSI [and more portable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/723195/should-i-use-or-for-not-equal-in-tsql/723426#723426).

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT id,x,y FROM `chars` WHERE `mapa`='1' AND `id`<>3
```