# How can I exclude a certain row from an MySQL query

Tags: mysql, row

I want to exclude a certain row from an MYSQL query.

```
SELECT * FROM imdb WHERE genres LIKE 'Adventure' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10
```

It's for a movie website, so I retrive similar Adventures movie, but this includes the current movie.

So I need something like this:

Select the movies like Adventures, but exclude this id: 1, yet, results 10 movies.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you know the exact id (say, id = 1 for example), do this:

```
SELECT * FROM imdb WHERE genres LIKE 'Adventure' AND id <> 1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10
```

See this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4574281/mysql-exclude-row).

Comment: Thank you, it did work, and actually I did this before, but visually in the MySQL results show me the id I wanted to exclude too, but the text was Showing rows 0 - 3 (4 total, Query took 0.0012 sec) [id: 243 - 229], so thank you again for brining the light.

Comment: @Wtstatscom: By the way, you can click the empty "Check Mark" symbol next to JW's answer to indicate that it worked for you =)

Comment: @jadarnel27 - Thank you & done, thank you guys. You were so fast with the replies.

Answer (score 5):

Something like this maybe?

```
SELECT * 
FROM imdb 
WHERE genres LIKE 'Adventure' AND
  ID NOT IN (1)
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10
```

You can put a list of IDs you don't want to include between the parenthesis after `NOT IN`.

EDIT: You could also put a query in between those parens if you know a particular group of ID's you want to exclude:

```
WHERE genres LIKE 'Adventure' AND
  ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM imdb WHERE LeadActor='Pauly Shore') --You know you want to exclude him =)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * FROM imdb WHERE genres LIKE 'Adventure' and id != 1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 0):

For not showing current user data, below is the query

```
$sql = "SELECT u1.parent_id, m1.meta_value AS headline
        FROM wp_vandor u1
        JOIN wp_usermeta m1 ON (m1.user_id = u1.child_id AND m1.meta_key = 'headline') 
        WHERE m1.user_id!=$currentuser_id";
```