# Difference between <> and != in SQL

Tags: sql

What is the exact **Difference between <> and !=** ?

Comment: I don't think there is, but you might want to be more specific about the sql dialect ... ANSI SQL (year?), Oracle, MS T-SQL, DB2, MySql, ...?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/723195/should-i-use-or-for-not-equal-in-tsql/723426#723426

Comment: Why this question should be close?

Comment: Well, the reason given for closing it is "not a real question". I don't see what justification there is for that, as it seems a pretty straight-forward question. If it's closed for that reason, I for one will be voting to re-open.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

None whatsoever, syntactically.

Both are inequality operators, `<>` is the SQL-92 standard, however its interchangable on some platforms with `!=` (E.g. SQL Server)

Answer (score 4):

`<>` is the only inequality operator in the SQL Standard.

Lot's of SQL database systems support the use of `!=` including PostgreSQL, SQL Server, MySQL, SQLite, Oracle & Firebird, but some don't, including Apache Derby.

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle there is no difference.  Can't speak for all other databases.

Comment: @Vijjendra: When you say "SQL" it may be that you mean "Microsoft SQL Server", but to many of us "SQL" is a query language supported by many database products, among them Oracle, PostgreSQL, MySQL, Firebird, Rdb, Microsoft Access, and many others.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference, at least for MySQL.

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html

Answer (score 1):

Both are used in SQL Server. Both are used for same purpose. SQL Server 2000 and its previous version don't support != but SQL Server 2005 and SQL Server 2008 supports both <> and !=

Answer (score 1):

Functionally there's no difference.

I think this is a matter of programmer preference: '<>' may be preferred by programmers who use various flavors of Pascal or Basic, while '!=' may be preferred by those who use languages which are descendants of C (e.g. C++, Java, C#).  Interestingly, though, the C-style equality comparison operator ('==') is not supported in Oracle - how about in other flavors of SQL?

Share and enjoy.