# difference between <> and !=

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Oracle <> , != , ^= operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12003127/oracle-operators)

in sql, what is the difference between `<>` and `!=`, we can use both for "`NOt Equal to`".

is there any difference in between them? 
ex.

```
select * from student where no != 2;
```

&

```
select * from student where no <> 2;
```

is any advantage of using one insted of another?

What are the main factors because of which `!=` is not made as  ISO standard

Comment: Might want to search the archives first before posting. A very quick search returned http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5856439/difference-between-and-in-sql which seems to ask/answer the same question.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**For SQL Server:**

They are the same. Both are two ***Not Equal To*** operators. But `!=` is not ISO standard, as quoted from [**Comparison Operators**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188074.aspx):

> <> (Not Equal To) Not equal to
>
> != (Not Equal To) Not equal to (not ISO standard)