# What does "<>" mean in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

What does <> mean in SQL language: Sample code is as follows

```
SELECT ordid,
       prodid,
       qty
FROM   item
WHERE  prodid IN (SELECT prodid
                  FROM   item
                  WHERE  ordid = 605)
       AND qty IN (SELECT qty
                   FROM   item
                   WHERE  ordid = 605)
       AND ordid <> 605;
```

Comment: Welcome! If you've an answer to your problem, click the outline tick next to the correct solution. There's no need to edit your post.

Comment: @Jay - I deleted my answer as I had misread the query originally. The conditions aren't contradictory at all. Somewhat clearer with the reformatted query!

Comment: No worries Martin, sorry about that. The answer we are given is "Display the order number, product number, and quantity of any item in which the product number and quantity match any product number and any quantity of an item in order 605." Although I am still little confused

Comment: @MartinSmith Also I was wondering if you have any resources that have all the conditions and operators that can help me revise?

Comment: @Jay - [They seem to be covered here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Oracle/0460__PL-SQL-Operators/LogicalOperatorsinPLSQL.htm)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

It means 'not equal to'. So you're filtering out records where `ordid` is 605. Overall you're looking for any records which have the same `prodid` and `qty` values as those assigned to `ordid` 605, but which are for a different order.

Answer (score 12):

Does not equal. The opposite of `=`, equivalent to `!=`.

Also, for everyone's info, this can return a non-zero number of rows. I see the OP has reformatted his question so it's a bit clearer, but as far as I can tell, this finds records where product ID is among those found in order #605, as is quantity, but it's not actually order #605. If order #605 contains 1 apple, 2 bananas and 3 crayons, #604 should match if it contains 2 apples (but not 3 dogs). It just won't match order #605. (And if `ordid` is unique, then it would find exact duplicates.)

Comment: `=` and `!=` are NOT opposites in respect to `NULL`:
`1 = NULL` will not evaluate to true, but neither does `1 != NULL` .

`SELECT CASE WHEN 1=NULL THEN 'same' WHEN 1!=NULL THEN 'diff' ELSE 'yup Null' END FROM DUAL;` Shows that NULL is the symetry-breaker.

Answer (score 5):

I'm surprised nobody mentioned the `null` special case. I think the meaning of `<>` is more something like

> has a value which is not equal to

In this case it filters out items which have `ordid` 605 *and* items which have a `null` `ordid`.

It may be obvious in this context that `ordid` is never `null`, but it is never hurts to remember that `null` is **not** `<>` from 605 (or from anything).

Answer (score 4):

It just means "different of", some languages uses `!=`, others (like SQL) `<>`

Answer (score 4):

`not equals`. See [here](http://psoug.org/reference/conditions.html) for a list of conditions

Answer (score 0):

It means `not equal to`

[Should I use != or <> for not equal in TSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/723195/should-i-use-or-for-not-equal-in-tsql)

Have a look at the link. It has detailed explanation of what to use for what.

Answer (score 0):

`It (<>) is a function that is used to compare values in database table.`

***!= (Not equal to) functions the same as the <> (Not equal to) comparison operator.***

Answer (score -1):

It means not equal to, this is a good method to exclude certain elements from your query. For example lets say you have an orders tables and then you have OrderStatusID column within that table.

You also have a status table where

```
0 = OnHold, 
1 = Processing, 
2 = WaitingPayment, 
3 = Shipped, 
4 = Canceled.
```

You can run a query where

```
Select * From [Orders] where OrderStatusID <> 4
```

this should give you all the orders except those that have been canceled! :D