# Querying two datatables

Tags: linq, datatable, vb.net-2010

In vb.net I have two datatables, `dt1` and `dt2`. Both have only one column.

Now I need another table `dt3` which should have the rows of `dt1` that are not present in `dt2`.

I tried to do with LINQ:

```
Dim results = From table1 In dt1 
              Join table2 In dt2 On table1(0) Equals table2(0) 
              Select table1(0)
```

But this returns only that are matching. But I need the opposite (rows not there in `dt2`).

Is it possible doing without LINQ?

Comment: Earlier post explains how to do it in SQL: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8165534/select-rows-not-in-another-table-sql-server-query

Comment: VB.net is **NOT** a database engine or interface, you use something else (like SQL) to connect to the database from VB.net  
You asked about doing it **WITHOUT** LINQ. I gave you the pointer to the answer. If you **DO** want to do it with LINQ try reading this too http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386976.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand, you don't need a join (as you are selecting only rows from the first table). You can use a LINQ query like

```
From table1 In dt1 _
Where Not (From table2 In dt2 Where table2(0) = table1(0)).Any() _
Select table1(0)
```

Comment: Its throwing error: "Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Chars' accepts this number of arguments."

Comment: My bad. Given correct datatype. Changed that. Now it is working fine. Thanks :)