# Select combination of fields not in other table sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's say I have these two tables:

```
    Table 1                        Table 2
  PName  |   FID                 PName   |  FID
  ----------------               ---------------
  Dog    |   1                   Dog     |  1
  Dog    |   2                   Cat     |  2
  Cat    |   2                   Cat     |  4
  Cat    |   3
```

What is the right query to select the two fields combinations of the first table that are not present in the second?

What I want to get is

```
    Table 1                      
  PName  |   FID                 
  ----------------               
  Dog    |   2                   
  Cat    |   3
```

Would that be?

```
SELECT * FROM [Table 1] WHERE ([Table 1].[PName] NOT IN (SELECT [Table 2].[PName] FROM [Table 2]) AND ([Table 1].[FID] NOT IN (SELECT [Table 2].[FID] FROM [Table 2]))
```

Comment: @user7733611 you posted a link to this question

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering why it wasn't working... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8165534/select-rows-not-in-another-table-sql-server-query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use [`except`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-except-and-intersect-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

```
select * from table1
except
select * from table2
```

It's worth mentioning [this great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1664153/6167855) discussing `except` vs `not in` especially in regards to `NULL`

Answer (score 2):

I might suggest something like the following:

```
select t1.* 
from table1 t1 
where not exists (select 1  
                  from table2 t2 
                  where t2.pname = t1.pname and t2.fid = t1.fid
                 );
```

Comment: This is useful for other technologies such as MySQL, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need a left join and take only the rows where there is no match:

```
select t1.*
from t1 left join t2
on t1.pname = t2.pname and t1.fid = t2.fid
where t2.pname is null and t2.fid is null
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e667295f8b9ad1b9b7d93b83ae31582d)