# What is the syntax for "not equal" in SQLite?

Tags: android, sqlite

```
 Cursor findNormalItems = db.query("items", columns, "type=?", 
                                   new String[] { "onSale" });
```

I want to return the cursor that points anything that are NOT onSale, what should I change? Thanks!

Answer (score 219, accepted):

From [the official documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html):

> The non-equals operator can be either `!=` or `<>`

So your code becomes:

```
Cursor findNormalItems = db.query("items", columns, "type != ?", 
                                  new String[] { "onSale" });
```

Comment: In my opinion, `!=` looks more professional - and is more consistent with the `=` and `==` operators.

Comment: why I have to add "OR 'mycolumn' IS NOT NULL ? When I query with a where clause NOT EQUAL ?

Comment: @ban-geoengineering `<>` is SQL Ansi standard and `!=` is not. Of course `<>` is more professional

Comment: @ban-geoengineering, here is [a bunch of comments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/723317) presenting arguments for usage of `!=` or `<>`.

Answer (score 10):

You should use in the comparator the non-equal operator:
 `"type!=?"` or `"type<>?"`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `<>` operator

You will find here all the basic `sql` statements

http://www.firstsql.com/tutor2.htm

Answer (score -1):

With rawQuery :

```
quranCursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * from alquran WHERE sura_id = '" + sooraId + "' AND ayat_id !='" + "0" + "'", null);
```

Usage:

```
     int sooraId = 3 ;
    
        try {
          // start from not 0, but 1 ; Include All row but ayat_id = 0 : 
          quranCursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * from alquran WHERE sura_id = '" + sooraId + "' AND ayat_id !='" + "0" + "'", null);
  
        } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

This is tested  one of my app, and works fine, Alhamdulillah.