# comparison operator objects in java

Tags: java, operators, operator-keyword

Are there any object representation of these comparison operators (<, <=, ==, >=, >, !=) in Java ?

E.g. use case:

```
void filterHotel( Object operator, float rating ) {

    String query = "SELECT hotel.name from hotel where hotel.rating " + 
operator.toString() + rating;    
    // execute query
}
```

Comment: Just write your own, it'll take 5 minutes..

Comment: Why not just a `String`?

Comment: Java is not c++.  You can not override operators in java.

Comment: @paislee: actually I admire people who always check whether maybe *this small thingy* already exists. Otherwise we end up with duplication and code harder to port.

Comment: Why? You're writing SQL in the form of a string. Why would the SQL operators be so special that you'd want to extract those? If you're doing that, why stop at the operators, why not extract SELECT and FROM and WHERE keywords too? Or the dot and the comma, and what have you? I can imagine that it makes sense to externalize those things that actually differ between RDBMS platforms. To crack that problem, the operators are probably least of your worries.

Comment: I thought `<>` rather than `!=` was standard SQL.

Comment: @PeterLawrey - Absolutely right. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/723426/535871)

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz: Yep, I asked for the same reason :). There's like so many things happening, so there's always a good chance that the wheel has already been invented!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No**. But it is easy to write, consider using `enum` with custom method:

```
public enum Operator {
    EQUAL("=="),
    NOT_EQUAL("<>"),
    GREATER_THAN(">"),
    GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL(">="),
    LESS_THAN("<"),
    LESS_THAN_OR_EQUAL("<=");

    private final String representation;

    private Operator(String representation) {
        this.representation = representation;
    }

    public String getRepresentation() {
        return representation;
    }
}
```

Pass e.g. `Operator.LESS_THAN` and extract actual operator using `operator.getRepresentation()`.

Also make sure user cannot put arbitrary string in place of `operator` to avoid [sql-injection](/questions/tagged/sql-injection).

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing built in, but you can define an `enum` that does the trick:

```
public enum ComparisonOperator {
    LT("<"), LE("<="), EQ("=="), NE("<>"), GE(">="), GT(">");

    ComparisonOperator(String symbol) { this.symbol = symbol; }
    private final String symbol;
    public String toSymbol() { return symbol; }
}
```

Then:

```
void filterHotel(ComparisonOperator operator, float rating) {

    String query = "SELECT hotel.name from hotel where hotel.rating " + 
        operator.toSymbol() + rating;    
    // execute query
}
```