# Can I add if clause in where clause 

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

In stored procedure I have:

```
@parameter int
```

based on this parameter I get some data it can be -1 or greater than 0.

Problem is that if it is -1 I don't want to this parameter be in where clause at all.

So what I am trying to do is something like:

```
IF @parameter = -1 THEN
WHERE ...
ELSE
where ... AND Column = @parameter
```

But this doesn't work.

Comment: You have a column named Column?

Comment: little word of caution if you are aiming at "catch all queries" as they can perform badly if you don't take into account (and counter) execution plan caching: http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Typically you'd apply that constraint like this:

```
WHERE [...] AND (@parameter = -1 OR Column = @parameter)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
where 
  @parameter != - 1 AND Column = @parameter
```

The diff between Dan J and my answer is that nothing is matched if @parameter is -1. Dan J returns everything and is the behaviour you probably want.

Comment: I like mine better (and `!=` isn't the SQL not-equal operator). ;)

Comment: != and <> work all the same in sql server no? What is the not-equal operator then?

Comment: Ah, you're right, SQL Server supports `!=`. I've always used `<>`, which I believe [is ANSI standard](http://stackoverflow.com/a/723317/238688).