# What is difference between operater != and <> in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should I use != or <> for not equal in TSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/723195/should-i-use-or-for-not-equal-in-tsql)

Behavior of both operator is same. But i want to know about
What is difference between operater **!=** and **<>** in SQL Server?

Comment: One is ANSI one isn't. Duplicate...

Comment: @MartinSmith: I thinks the question differs in that the OP asks on what is the fundamental difference between the operators rather than which one to use.

Comment: @mankand007 - There is no fundamental difference. They are functionally identical. This question is basically a sub question of the other. if there were any fundamental difference it would be addressed there.

Comment: It's quite easy to find the difference in the docs ... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190296.aspx Took 10secs to find. I don't see the point of asking it here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically both `!=` and `<>` are same. Even if you use them in stored procedures also they will behave same in terms of performance. As a [SQL standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL) you should prefer `<>`.

**NOTE:** `!=` operator is not standard SQL.

Answer (score 2):

They are equivalent. The only difference is that the `<>` is ISO standard, the `!=` is not.

Check out this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188074.aspx

Answer (score 0):

`a <> b` basically checks that a is either less than or greater than b; i.e, not equal to b. I believe both a and b are converted to their ascii values and then compared.