# Selecting filtered rows with SQL

Tags: sql

I am constructing an SQL statement with some parameters. Finally, an SQL statement is created like 
`"select * from table where column1 = "xyz"`".

But I also need the rows which are filtered with this statement. In this case they're rows which are not "xyz" valued in column1. More specifically, I am looking for something like `INVERSE(select * from table where ...)`. Is it possible?

Edit: My bad, I know I can do it with != or operator. Here the case is, select statement may be more complex (with some ANDs and equal, greater operators). Let's assume a table has A,B,C and my SQL statement brings only A as result. But I need B and C while I only have the statement which brings A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was :

`"select * from table where rowId NOT IN (select rowId from table where column1 = "xyz")`

I needed a unique rowId column to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

`select * from table where column1 != 'xyz' or column1 is null;`

Answer (score 0):

If you want the other ones, do it like this:

```
select * from table where column1 <> "xyz"
```

column1 <> (differs from) "xyz"

Answer (score 0):

To check if something is no equal you can use `<>` or even `!=`

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE <> 'xyz'
```

OR

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE != 'xyz'
```

Many database vendors [support (see list)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/723195/should-i-use-or-for-not-equal-in-tsql/723426#723426)  both versions of the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

If you're retrieving both result sets at about the same time, and just want to process the `xyz` ones first, you could do:

```
select *,CASE WHEN column1 = "xyz" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as xyz from table
order by CASE WHEN column1 = "xyz" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END desc
```

This will return all of the rows in one result set. Whilst `xyz` = 1, these were the rows with `column1` = `'xyz'`.