# How to Replace IS NULL and != with a Built-in TSQL Function?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, isnull

Is there any simple function in TSQL that could replace the below tsql?

```
SELECT * FROM Users
WHERE (Username IS NULL OR Username != @username)
```

I could write the below but that's not bullet proof due to the hard coded text!

```
 SELECT * FROM Users
    WHERE ISNULL(Username, 'dummytext') != @username
```

Thanks,

Comment: What do you want to replace and why?

Comment: To use a built-in function if any exists and be shorter.

Comment: Your original SQL is short and clear. I see no reason to replace it unless you run into performance problems. In case you do, you should look at Jack Douglas answer, which may be able to utilize an index.

Answer (score 3):

In this instance I don't think its worth having a UDF to manage this condition.

`(Username IS NULL OR Username != @username)` is **43** characters long

`dbo.IsNullorNotEqual(Username, @Username)=0` is **43** characters long

---

Sure, you could make the function name slightly shorter, but its not worth breaking convention to make a function call shorter.

Furthermore, not using a UDF in this instance will let you see *exactly* whats going on.

Answer (score 2):

Daniel asked good question...

My 3 cents:

1. Using function make **impossible to use index** :(.
2. However `!=` operator is supported by most databases (based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/723426/1483), `<>` is ANSI compliant.
3. You can use `COALESCE()` instead of `ISNULL()` but it still function which blocking using index :(.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not certain what you are trying to achieve, but does this help?

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/236fd/11)

**Schema Setup**:

```
create table Users(Username varchar(99));
insert into Users(Username) values('Alice');
insert into Users(Username) values('Bob');
insert into Users(Username) values(null);
```

**Query 1**:

```
DECLARE @username varchar(99)
SET @username = 'Alice'
SELECT * FROM Users 
EXCEPT
SELECT * FROM Users where Username = @username
```

**Results**:

```
| USERNAME |
------------
|   (null) |
|      Bob |
```