# <> operator not working in query

Tags: php, sql

Let's focus on **event_table** column. What I'm trying to do is getting all value except for "0"

[image]

Here is my query for that,

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT event_table FROM embedded_page WHERE event_table <> 0 AND uid='". $uid ."'";
$result = db_query($query);
foreach ($result as $r) {

    echo $r->event_table;
}
```

I'm trying to select event_table's values with distinct to prevent duplication. but since, I'm using the operator <> for some reason, it doesn't work. when I echoed it, **no output**

if I removed the **event_table <> 0**  it outputs 0, giveaway_table, and poll

Comment: try using `!=` instead of `<> `

Comment: @shnisaka what for? Are you sure `<>` doesn't work?

Comment: @Wesley To let you know, there is no `<>` operator in PDO

Comment: @YourCommonSense some databases do not support `<>` .. search for it and see for yourself

Comment: @shnisaka, can you name one SQL database that doesn't support `<>`?  I think I covered the major ones here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/723195/should-i-use-or-for-not-equal-in-tsql/723426#723426

Comment: @BillKarwin this question could help you with your research.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166966/what-is-the-point-of-the-diamond-operator-in-java-7
Also, if you you google "diamond operator not supported" you will see a bunch of different languages that do not support them.

Comment: @shnisaka, that's about the Java generics diamond operator, not the "not equal to" operator in SQL.  The google search you suggested shows only references to the Java generics diamond operator, and a diamond-operator notation in number theory, which also has nothing to do with with SQL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
 event_table <> '0'
```

You are comparing to a string column, but specifying an integer value, and it appears that either PDO or your underlying database is not handling the int to string conversion in the way you expect.

Also, your code sample is vulnerable to [Sql Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Comment: Yes, watch out for SQL injections. At the very least cast $uid to an int.