# how to negate the following SQL statement?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following conditional sql statement, which works.. but I have an empty statement in the if part... I want to negate it so that I can just use the if part with the logic

```
    IF @WorkPrescribed = 1 and (@DefectNo1 = @WorkPrescribedDefectNo or @DefectNo2 = @WorkPrescribedDefectNo or @DefectNo3 = @WorkPrescribedDefectNo or @DefectNo4 = @WorkPrescribedDefectNo)
  BEGIN
            -- I don't want this at all.. only reason I have this is so I can have the else condition
  END
    else
        BEGIN
             --My current logic is all here
        END
```

so I just want to know how to negate what I have, so I can do everything just with an If, rather than use the else

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps simply

```
IF NOT(@WorkPrescribed = 1 and (@DefectNo1 = @WorkPrescribedDefectNo or @DefectNo2 = @WorkPrescribedDefectNo or @DefectNo3 = @WorkPrescribedDefectNo or @DefectNo4 = @WorkPrescribedDefectNo))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply negate the logic by enclosing with a `NOT()`, or you could write like this:

```
IF @WorkPrescribed != 1 or (@DefectNo1 != @WorkPrescribedDefectNo and @DefectNo2 != @WorkPrescribedDefectNo and @DefectNo3 != @WorkPrescribedDefectNo and @DefectNo4 != @WorkPrescribedDefectNo)
    BEGIN
         --My current logic is all here
    END
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put `NOT` "around" the statement to be negated:

```
IF NOT (@WorkPrescribed = 1 and (@DefectNo1 = @WorkPrescribedDefectNo or @DefectNo2 = @WorkPrescribedDefectNo or @DefectNo3 = @WorkPrescribedDefectNo or @DefectNo4 = @WorkPrescribedDefectNo))
  BEGIN
            -- I don't want this at all.. only reason I have this is so I can have the else condition
  END
    else
        BEGIN
             --My current logic is all here
        END
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IF @WorkPrescribed <> 1` instead of `=` operator

check this post.
[Should I use != or <> for not equal in TSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/723195/should-i-use-or-for-not-equal-in-tsql)

or you can use

```
IF NOT @WorkPrescribed = 1 and 
(@DefectNo1 = @WorkPrescribedDefectNo or 
 @DefectNo2 = @WorkPrescribedDefectNo or 
 @DefectNo3 = @WorkPrescribedDefectNo or 
 @DefectNo4 = @WorkPrescribedDefectNo)
```

Comment: that should not negate the whole statement but only the first part `@WorkPrescribed = 1`

Answer (score 0):

```
IF @WorkPrescribed <> 1 
or @WorkPrescribedDefectNo not in (@DefectNo1, @DefectNo2, @DefectNo3, @DefectNo4)
BEGIN
 -- code
END
```