# Not Equals performance

Tags: sql, performance, t-sql, syntax, sqlperformance

Is there a difference in performance between `!=` and `<>`?

**Bonus:** why do people get upset when I use `!=` instead of `<>`? I am of course speculating that all programmers get upset about this, however I have worked for two companies now that "require" the use of `<>`

Comment: @GuilhermeSehn can you convert your response to an answer please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: no, there's no difference in performance.

As for the bonus question, I imagine people get upset because `!=` is not defined in the SQL 92 standard and is therefore less likely to be portable.

#### Edit

The SQL 92 standard can be found [here](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/%7Eshadow/sql/sql1992.txt) and defines the **not equals** operator as follows:

```
<not equals operator> ::= <>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer to the bonus.  Can you sight sources for your answer to the question?

Answer (score 1):

They do not have performance differences, it's certainly for matters of standards/consistence. Take a look at this question: [Should I use != or <> for not equal in TSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/723195/should-i-use-or-for-not-equal-in-tsql)