# TSQL Boolean Comparison Syntax

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, comparison

In TSQL is it proper to use != or should one always use <> when doing Boolean comparisons? Is there any difference in performance between the two?

Comment: No difference - just personal preference

Comment: `!=`  is not ISO standard, `<>` works in all rdbms.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should I use != or <> for not equal in TSQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/723195/should-i-use-or-for-not-equal-in-tsql)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No difference just like @marc_s said but if do put it in into SQL server it will just convert it to `<>`

Just execute the following 2 statements,

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.databases
WHERE database_id != 1


SELECT *
FROM sys.databases
WHERE database_id <> 1
```

you will see in Actual execute plan both queries will look like this, and both have same execution plans

```
SELECT * FROM [sys].[databases] WHERE [database_id]<>@1
```

Answer (score 0):

There is absolutely no difference in using != OR <> OPERATORS. In terms of performance, you will see no change. I use <> just to keep me aware of mistake.