# SQL Query to show records

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I am trying to figure out what SQL query I need to fetch records from my users table.

```
"SELECT * FROM users WHERE level!='4'"
```

Level 4 users are "COMPLETED" so by default, they are not shown.
But I do want to show users that are COMPLETED if their ACTIVITY value is less than 5.
Any user with an activity value of 5 is "Green" and does not require my attention.

Knowing my luck, it's a very simple answer, but it's been a long day and my head is fried.

Comment: Post your table structure and some sample data

Comment: is it mysql or SQL Server?

Comment: In equality is denoted by <> for most databases. You can use != but it has to be database specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do like so:

```
SELECT * 
FROM users 
WHERE level <> '4'
OR (level = '4' and Activity < 5);
```

I've switched the inequality operator - `<>` [is more portable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/723426/314291)

Comment: Good guess on the schema!

Answer (score 2):

This should solve your problem

> SELECT * FROM users WHERE level != '4' OR (activity < '5' AND level =
>   '4' )

Answer (score 0):

simple method like following as:

```
SELECT * FROM users
LIMIT 4;
```

Comment: This answer is insufficient

Comment: @ Craigy Craigo, i didn't understand, why you ask insufficient answer.

Comment: @Craigy Craigo, if you have table in 5 rows its should be showing limit is 4.

Comment: I'm afraid you do not quite understand the problem. The answer I was looking for is located above.

Comment: @CraigyCraigo, oh k, I'll understand,.. I refer that answer, sorry buddy.