# Is there a better way to make this query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, t-sql

I would like to know if there is a better way to write the following query:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * 
           FROM   master_list 
           WHERE  code = 'r_params') 
  BEGIN 
      UPDATE master_list 
      SET    code = 'w_params' 
      WHERE  code = 'r_params' 
             AND NOT name_1 = 'pH' 
             AND NOT name_2 = 'Flow' 
             AND NOT name_3 = 'Temperature' 

      SELECT * 
      FROM   r_master_list 
      WHERE  code = 'r_params' 

      SELECT * 
      FROM   r_master_list 
      WHERE  code = 'w_params' 
  END
```

Thanks

Comment: Use `<>` instead of `not =`

Comment: or use `!=` which has same meaning

Comment: What is your actual problem with your code? Doesn't it run? Please specify a concrete problem as questions asking for "better" solutions are off-topic at Stack Overflow.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should I use != or <> for not equal in TSQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/723195/should-i-use-or-for-not-equal-in-tsql)

Comment: Must you absolutely return two resultsets? Why not a single one where code is either r_params or w_params?

Comment: Thank you! I will return a single result set.

Comment: Also, you are of course aware that the condition in your `EXISTS` query isn't the same as in your `UPDATE` statement?

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT 1` may be faster

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 
           FROM   master_list 
           WHERE  code = 'r_params') 
  BEGIN 
      UPDATE master_list 
      SET    code = 'w_params' 
      WHERE  code = 'r_params' 
             AND name_1 <> 'pH' 
             AND name_2 <> 'Flow' 
             AND name_3 <> 'Temperature' 

      SELECT * 
      FROM   r_master_list 
      WHERE  code = 'r_params' 

      SELECT * 
      FROM   r_master_list 
      WHERE  code = 'w_params' 
  END
```

Comment: are you sure? I would have thought that the `EXISTS` function would be clever enough not to return any fields...

Comment: @Crono I do believe there may actually be some debate over the issue:

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/02/26/sql-server-select-1-vs-select-an-interesting-observation/

Comment: Seems like there are lots of people claiming this to be right, yet there are as many saying the opposite. Either way, I *do* see something good with this approach: it would allow you to search through your code base for queries starting with `SELECT *` without needlessly reaching such queries nested into `EXISTS` function. It's a bit of a long shot, but still that's valuable.

Comment: +1  I am not sure if it is faster but I think it makes the intent of the statement more clear

Answer (score 0):

```
if exists (select * from MASTER_LIST where Code = 'r_params')
begin
    update MASTER_LIST 
      set Code = 'w_params' 
      where Code = 'r_params' 
      AND  Name_1 <> 'pH' 
      AND  Name_2 <> 'Flow' 
      AND  Name_3 <> 'Temperature'

 select * from R_MASTER_LIST  WHERE Code = 'r_params'

 select * from R_MASTER_LIST WHERE Code = 'w_params'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Putting aside the form in which the client expects to receive the data, a better way would be to **combine the two resultsets into one**:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * 
    FROM   master_list 
    WHERE  code = 'r_params') 
BEGIN 
    UPDATE master_list 
    SET    code = 'w_params' 
    WHERE  code = 'r_params' 
        AND name_1 <> 'pH' 
        AND name_2 <> 'Flow' 
        AND name_3 <> 'Temperature' 

    SELECT * 
    FROM   r_master_list 
    WHERE  code IN ('r_params', 'w_params')
END
```

This way you are making ONE query on `r_master_list` rather than two. The client will receive the exact same data; only it will be his responsibility to split it into distinct resultsets, should he need to. Performance and efficiency-wise, that should be the preferred solution.

**UPDATE:**

As Drew suggests you may also want to make your `EXISTS' function subquery like this instead:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 
FROM   master_list 
    WHERE  code = 'r_params')
```

There is quite a debate over this being more efficient or not. Drew seems to believe it is; I for one can't tell. BUT! There's still an advantage with this approach that Drew didn't mention: if you ever want to find `SELECT` queries using `*` for fields throughout your codebase, you will find it convenient that all of your `EXISTS` functions subqueries uses the `SELECT 1` pattern so that you won't reach out to those needlessly. It may not be much but still I thought it was worth mentionning.

Answer (score 0):

This is redundant
One of the condition on the update is WHERE  code = 'r_params'

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * 
           FROM   master_list 
           WHERE  code = 'r_params')
```

This is sufficient

```
  UPDATE master_list 
  SET    code = 'w_params' 
  WHERE  code = 'r_params' 
         AND NOT name_1 = 'pH' 
         AND NOT name_2 = 'Flow' 
         AND NOT name_3 = 'Temperature' 

  SELECT * 
  FROM   r_master_list 
  WHERE  code = 'r_params' 

  SELECT * 
  FROM   r_master_list 
  WHERE  code = 'w_params'
```

The only difference is that you would get the last select even is there were no 'r_params'

The last two can be combined

```
SELECT * 
  FROM r_master_list 
 WHERE code in  ('r_params','w_params') 
 order by code
```