# What does <> mean on SQL

Tags: mysql

I was looking for what the <> mean on sql syntax but it was hard to google for it since google removes my special characters.

Specifically I was trying to figure out what the following means:

```
... AND (s1.skips > 0 OR s1.fails <> 1 OR s2.skips > 0);
```

Is there any clear documentation talking about the <> clause?

Comment: `<>` means not equal. See also [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/723195/should-i-use-or-for-not-equal-in-tsql).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<>` is the equivalent of `!=` in many other programming languages.

Specifically, your MySQL query makes the following restrictions if any of these are true:

- `s1.skips > 0` - Number of **s1** skips is **greater than 0**
- `s1.fails <> 1` - Number of **s1** fails **is NOT 1**
- `s2.skips > 0` - Number of **s2** skips is **greater than 0**

Answer (score 6):

Please have a look at the documentation.

[Comparison Functions and Operators](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_not-equal)

Answer (score 4):

Of course, it's the "not equal"-operator, same as !=, see [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_not-equal)