# Security in my PHP script

Tags: php, mysql, security, get

I found this source code in a website I just purchased. Just wondering if this script is secure? Can anyone explain this to me?

```
<?php

if($_GET['map_loc']) {
    $code = $_GET['map_loc'];
    $result= mysql_query("SELECT ttc.continent_id, ttc.continent_id, c.name FROM territories_to_continents ttc
        INNER JOIN continents c
        ON ttc.continent_id = c.continent_id
        WHERE ttc.code = '$code'
        LIMIT 1;
        ");
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    $mapLoc = $row['name'];
}

?>
```

Comment: It's insecure: http://bobby-tables.com  Plus it's just bad code. You simply assume your query can never fail and blindly execute/fetch data from the results. Any failure at any stage will trash later stages.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/723195/should-i-use-or-for-not-equal-in-tsql

Comment: I'm glad you ask this question because the code is totally insecure! Don't use the old MySQL extension. Use MySQLi or PDO, and regardless of which extension you choose, use Prepared Statements!

Comment: use [PDO](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers) or Mysqli. If you are too lazy, use [pdo wrapper](https://github.com/simon-eQ/PdoWrapper)

Comment: The stock answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1 - kudos for actually asking!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It absolutely not secure.... `mysql_*` is old and shouldn't be used. You should use PDO or mysqli instead, In the following example, I showed how it could be done with mysqli.

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['map_loc'])) {
    $code = $_GET['map_loc'];

    $query = "SELECT ttc.continent_id, ttc.continent_id, c.name FROM territories_to_continents ttc
                INNER JOIN continents c
                ON ttc.continent_id = c.continent_id
                WHERE ttc.code = ?
                LIMIT 1";

    if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query)){
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $code);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($ttc.continent_id1, $ttc.continent_id2, $mapLoc);
        $stmt->fetch();
        $stmt->free_result();
        $stmt->close();
    }
}
?>
```

You should definitely check out this famous question for help: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?lq=1)

Comment: This is secure, but the API is messy. Look at all those calls.

Comment: You would use `isset` to avoid notice of unknown key.

Comment: @Scott I mean you could remove `$stmt->free_result();` and `$stmt->close();` but I think the code looks more complete if you include the calls for closes for memory management and good practice purposes

Comment: Heh. I prefer write my own class as a sanity API for PDO. Then I just say $result = $db->query($sql, $param_array);

Comment: @Scott yeah i agree! But mysqli is a bit easier for new php programmers to understand.