# What is the difference between != and <> operators?

Tags: postgresql

I don't like not knowing this as there may be situations when I need to use one instead of the other. It seems in most cases they produce the same results but I am taking a guess they have subtle difference, maybe to do with NULL values or one does strict comparisons like the extra = in PHP does.

Thanks

Answer (score 70, accepted):

From the [manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-comparison.html):

> Note: The != operator is converted to <> in the parser stage. It is not possible to implement != and <> operators that do different things.

So no, there is no difference between the two.

Answer (score 13):

`<>` is the standard SQL operator meaning "not equal". Many databases, including postgresql, supports `!=` as a synonym for `<>`.

They're exactly the same in postgresql. 
See also the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/functions-comparison.html).

Note though, that postgresql allows you to implement your own types and
overload operators for those types, so ultimately it depends on the datatypes involved what the `!=` and `<>` operator actually does, but `<>` and `!=` can never do different things.

Answer (score 1):

According to this: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-comparison.html
The operator `!=` gets transformed to `<>` in the parse stage.

Answer (score 1):

Being curious I found out that the conversion is defined in [`/src/backend/parser/scan.l`](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/src/backend/parser/scan.l#L888):

```
/* Convert "!=" operator to "<>" for compatibility */
if (strcmp(yytext, "!=") == 0)
    yylval->str = pstrdup("<>");
else
    yylval->str = pstrdup(yytext);
return Op;
```

`scan.l` is used almost at the beginning of parsing. There is also note in [Create Operator](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createoperator.html) chapter:

> The operator != is mapped to <> on input, so these two names are always equivalent.

You can find `<>` operator in `pg_operator` table, but there is nothing for `!=`:

```
select * from pg_operator where oprname = '<>';
select * from pg_operator where oprname = '!=';
```

There is a lot on this topic in this similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/723195/should-i-use-or-for-not-equal-in-tsql).