# Is there a difference between <> and != in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I just wanted to know if there is a difference between <> and != when expressing inequality in SQL queries.

Comment: I've found the duplicate question in 5 seconds.

Comment: Yes.  `<>` is the ANSI standard.  `!=` is a common synonym.  Functionally they are equivalent but not all databases support `!=`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically these both function are the same, so you may choose whichever you find more readable.

The [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/723195/should-i-use-or-for-not-equal-in-tsql) has a relevant line:

> '<>' is from the [SQL-92 standard](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt), '!=' is a **[proprietary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188074%28SQL.90%29.aspx)** T-SQL
>   operator.

Also to note that there are may database which doesnot `!=` but since you have tagged it as SQL Server then there is no differenc between them