# SQL SELECT WHERE NOT EQUAL

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to SELECT from `usr_uploaded_content` WHERE the `id` is NOT equal to `$content_id` I'm just wondering how this could be achieved. Thankyou.

```
 SELECT * FROM `usr_uploaded_content` WHERE `id` != '$content_id' LIMIT 2
```

In this example I used the `!=` to demonstrate the not equal.

Comment: Also tag dbms!  (Perhaps MySQL?)

Comment: you have achieved ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `<>`. See [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/723195/should-i-use-or-for-not-equal-in-tsql/723426#723426) for more detail

```
SELECT * FROM `usr_uploaded_content` WHERE `id` <> '$content_id' LIMIT 2
```

Comment: beat me by 8 sec ^.^

Comment: @Vinie, could you please add [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/723426/1322150) link to your answer?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM `usr_uploaded_content` WHERE `id` <> '$content_id' LIMIT 2
```