# Filter out certain rows based on condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I have this Input Table:

```
+-------------+--------------+-------+
| ProjectName | ProjectOwner | Col2  |
+-------------+--------------+-------+
| A           | Sara         | Sara  |
| B           | Jack         | Maria |
| B           | Jack         | Jack  |
| C           | Laura        | May   |
| C           | Laura        | Laura |
| D           | Paul         | Jack  |
| E           | May          | May   |
| E           | May          | May   |
+-------------+--------------+-------+
```

I want to check each project separately then exclude

1. If the project owner has his name inside col2 and other people with him, then remove the row which is repetitive `Jack Jack`,

   a. For example, In Project B Jack has his name inside Col2 and he is working with Maria , so remove `Jack Jack`

   b. Also remove  `Laura Laura` in Project C
2. If Project owner only himself working inside the project then keep it, like Project A and Project E
3. If Project owner doesn't have his name inside col2 then exclude the project like Project D
4. Remove duplicate like Project E

Output Table:

```
+-------------+--------------+-------+
| ProjectName | ProjectOwner | Col2  |
+-------------+--------------+-------+
| A           | Sara         | Sara  |
| B           | Jack         | Maria |
| C           | Laura        | May   |
| E           | May          | May   | 
+-------------+--------------+-------+
```

I tried this [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/0218d/1/0) but the results didn't show me Project A and E.

Comment: Please clarify for 4: is there another table field for which you want to keep the min/max/something other entry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this code:

```
select distinct  *
from mytable m
where (ProjectOwner!=Col2 or not exists(select 1 from mytable m1 where m1.ProjectName=m.ProjectName and  m1.ProjectOwner=m.ProjectOwner and m.Col2!=m1.Col2) )
and ProjectName in (select ProjectName from mytable where ProjectOwner=Col2 )
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/0218d/90/0)

Comment: != won't work on sql server, the different-than operator is <>

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis != is a valid operator on SQL Server.

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis != and <> work in sql server 
please view this link [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/723195/should-i-use-or-for-not-equal-in-t-sql?answertab=active#tab-top)

Answer (score 0):

Use `EXISTS` WITH `ROW_NUMBER()` function :

```
select top (1) with ties *
from table t
where exists (select 1 
              from table t1 
              where t1.ProjectName = t.ProjectName and 
                    t1.Col2 = t.ProjectOwner
             )
order by dense_rank() over (partition by ProjectName 
                            order by (case when t.ProjectOwner = Col2 
                                           then 1 else 0 
                                       end)
                           );
```

Answer (score 0):

You may get the desired results by this nested SQL by using *GROUPING* and *COUNT* agggregation :

```
select ProjectName, ProjectOwner, Col2
  from
(  
   select ProjectName, ProjectOwner, Col2,
          count(1) over ( partition by ProjectName ) cnt
     from mytable
    group by ProjectName, ProjectOwner, Col2
) q
 where ( q.cnt = 1 or ProjectOwner != col2 )
   and ProjectOwner in ( select col2 from mytable );
```

[*SQL Fiddle Demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/0218d/87)