# How to write NOT EQUAL (!=) To Query For Implode Or explode

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a SQLquery equal to is working but when I try to change and run as != its not working Please  Help .

```
SELECT * FROM Database1 WHERE JobLevel IN != ('".$JobLevel_filter."')
```

I have to add not equal to query (!=) to job level .

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and [Question Checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). I'm afraid it's not at all clear what you're asking here.

Comment: Separately, please be sure only to use appropriate tags. Your question has nothing whatsoever to do with [tag:jquery].

Comment: You have multiple issues with your syntax in your select statement.  Get rid of the `IN` operator, get rid of the opening and closing parentheses `()` and change `!=` to `<>`.

Comment: @user12031119 `!=` and `<>` are the same thing https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_not-equal

Comment: You can't use both `IN` with `!=` . Maybe you mean `NOT IN` ? `!=` expect only one result

Comment: @ErgestBasha, that's fine, but my comment still takes a syntactically incorrect statement and makes it syntactically correct regardless if you change the not equal operator or not because the `IN` and `()` need to be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use "<>" or "not like 'ABC'" instead of "!="

Comment: [`!=`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_not-equal) is perfectly valid MySQL and standard SQL.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, `<>` alone is the ISO/ANSI <not equals operator> - at least since SQL-92 (I have no older pdf, so I can't check SQL-89 until the next time I go to the office.)

Comment: @jarlh - I guess I was misled by Wikipedia. But the fact remains that MySQL and [most others](https://stackoverflow.com/a/723426/157247) support it.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, I read customer code a couple of weeks ago where they still use `/=` for not equals to, and `!!` for concatenation. Old code never die.