# How do I not select some rows in sql using nodejs?

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js

I have the code

```
  const defer = Q.defer();
    var sql = "SELECT * FROM test WHERE type != ? AND externalUserId != ?";
    db.query(sql, [options.type, options.externalUserId], (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            console.dir(err);
            defer.reject(err);
        } else {
            defer.resolve(result);
        }
    });
    return defer.promise;
```

I'm trying to select all rows that don't have a certain type. The code above returns the wrong results. Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 0):

You should enclose all strings inside single quotes. Try this:
`"SELECT * FROM test WHERE type != '?' AND externalUserId != '?'"`

Also, I would recommend you use `<>` instead of `!=`. Here is [why](https://stackoverflow.com/a/723201/14555991).

Comment: I tried that but that didn't work.

Comment: Is it returning all rows?

Comment: It's returning 0 rows