# SQL fundamental question '!=' vs '<>' vs 'Not'

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Testing for inequality in T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7884/testing-for-inequality-in-t-sql)

Hi,

does there any different to use the '!=' vs '<>' vs 'Not'?

which one will have the worst performance

or it exist just because of the backward compatibility syntax?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7884/testing-for-inequality-in-t-sql

Answer (score 10):

- `NOT` does not always act the same
- `!=` or `<>` are identical, no deprecation mentioned. `<>` is ISO though

Comment: Yup; NOT is somewhat different. It's for things like "Blank NOT IN (stuff...)" or "Blank NOT NULL" and such.

Comment: @Andrew Barber: thanks, good example, I was just working on an example but yours covers it nicely

Comment: I was under the impression that it was actually `<>` that was the ANSI standard inequality operator.

Comment: @ninesided: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188074.aspx

Comment: @gbn: exactly, note the "not ISO standard" in parentheses next to `!=` on the linked table!

Comment: @onedaywhen, @ninesided: in my humble defence, it's early and not enough coffee. Thanks. gbn

Answer (score 5):

AFAIK, if you want to check for NULL, you must use `IS NOT` and not `!=` or `<>`

Comment: yeah `when 'foo' = null` returns `null`, not `true` or `false`

Comment: +1 @alxx: you could use `!=` or `<>` with the result of a COALESCE, though.