# Select all rows except based on two fields in MySQL

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id != 4;
SELECT * FROM table WHERE NOT id = 4;
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id <> 4;
```

I've got this all working but I also have to choose another field (or more fields) to decide what rows are returned.

How can I get this working?

Comment: You're already selecting all fields by using * - so I'm not clear on what your question is. And if you're asking about the difference bewteen those three methods of checking for inequality, then refer to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7884/testing-for-inequality-in-t-sql

Comment: the wording of your question was a little unclear so I tried to clarify. Please let me know if I've stuffed it up so it can be fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to 'deselect' columns where both conditions are true (`ID1` is 4 and `ID2` is 7), use something like:

```
select * from TBL where ID1 <> 4 or ID2 <> 7;

ID1  ID2  selected
---  ---  --------
 4    7     no
 4    1     yes
 1    7     yes
 1    1     yes
```

If you want to 'deselect' columns where either condition is true (`ID1` is 4 or `ID2` is 7), use something like:

```
select * from TBL where ID1 <> 4 and ID2 <> 7;

ID1  ID2  selected
---  ---  --------
 4    7     no
 4    1     no
 1    7     no
 1    1     yes
```

This can be extended to more conditions simply by adding them to the end of the `where` clause (and changing `both/either` to `all/any` in the text).

Comment: `where both conditions are true` implies `AND`

Comment: @zerk: except we're _deselecting_ them, not selecting them - that inverts the condition - I'll add the truth tables to clarify.

Comment: I'll accept this as an answer cause this were I get the idea.thank you so much. I have posted an answer to my question though.

Answer (score 0):

select * from albums where `idAlbum`!= 4 and `idAlbum`!= 8 I just solve my problem. Thanks for the help guys!