# In SQL Server, what does "SET ANSI_NULLS ON" mean?

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures

The definition says:

> When SET ANSI_NULLS is ON, a SELECT statement that uses WHERE column_name = NULL returns zero rows even if there are null values in column_name. A SELECT statement that uses WHERE column_name <> NULL returns zero rows even if there are non-null values in column_name.

Does this mean that no nulls will be included in this query?

```
SELECT Region
FROM employees
WHERE Region = @region
```

Or do `ANSI_NULL`s concern only queries like this one (where the `WHERE` includes the specific word `NULL`)?

```
SELECT Region
FROM employees
WHERE Region = NULL
```

Comment: Is the answer not already there in the 4th paragraph of the official documentation from which you copied the 1st paragraph, which is:-> "SET ANSI_NULLS ON affects a comparison only if one of the operands of the comparison is either a variable that is NULL or a literal NULL. If both sides of the comparison are columns or compound expressions, the setting does not affect the comparison."

Answer (score 92, accepted):

It means that no rows will be returned if `@region` is `NULL`, when used in your first example, even if there are rows in the table where `Region` is `NULL`.

When `ANSI_NULLS` is on (which you should always set on anyway, since the option to not have it on is going to be removed in the future), any comparison operation where (at least) one of the operands is `NULL` produces the third logic value - `UNKNOWN` (as opposed to `TRUE` and `FALSE`).

`UNKNOWN` values propagate through any combining boolean operators if they're not already decided (e.g. `AND` with a `FALSE` operand or `OR` with a `TRUE` operand) or negations (`NOT`).

The `WHERE` clause is used to filter the result set produced by the `FROM` clause, such that the overall value of the `WHERE` clause must be `TRUE` for the row to not be filtered out. So, if an `UNKNOWN` is produced by any comparison, it will cause the row to be filtered out.

---

@user1227804's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9766823/15498) includes this quote:

> If both sides of the comparison are columns or compound expressions, the setting does not affect the comparison.

from [`SET ANSI_NULLS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188048.aspx)<sup>*</sup>

However, I'm not sure what point it's trying to make, since if two `NULL` columns are compared (e.g. in a `JOIN`), the comparison still fails:

```
create table #T1 (
    ID int not null,
    Val1 varchar(10) null
)
insert into #T1(ID,Val1) select 1,null

create table #T2 (
    ID int not null,
    Val1 varchar(10) null
)
insert into #T2(ID,Val1) select 1,null

select * from #T1 t1 inner join #T2 t2 on t1.ID = t2.ID and t1.Val1 = t2.Val1
```

The above query returns 0 rows, whereas:

```
SELECT * FROM #T1 t1 INNER JOIN #T2 t2 
   ON t1.ID = t2.ID 
  AND (   t1.Val1 = t2.Val1 
       OR t1.Val1 IS NULL 
      AND t2.Val1 IS NULL   )
```

Returns one row. So even when both operands are columns, `NULL` does not equal `NULL`. And the [documentation for `=`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175118.aspx) doesn't have anything to say about the operands:

> When you compare two `NULL` expressions, the result depends on the `ANSI_NULLS` setting:
>
> If `ANSI_NULLS` is set to `ON`, the result is `NULL`<sup>1</sup>, following the ANSI convention that a `NULL` (or unknown) value is not equal to another `NULL` or unknown value.
>
> If `ANSI_NULLS` is set to `OFF`, the result of `NULL` compared to `NULL` is `TRUE`.
>
> Comparing `NULL` to a non-`NULL` value always results in `FALSE`<sup>2</sup>.

However, both <sup>1</sup> and <sup>2</sup> are incorrect - the result of both comparisons is `UNKNOWN`.

---

<sup>*</sup>The cryptic meaning of this text was finally discovered years later. What it actually means is that, for those comparisons, the setting has no effect and *it always acts as if the setting were ON*. Would have been clearer if it had stated that `SET ANSI_NULLS OFF` was the setting that had no effect.

Comment: so if i understand you right: it effects the result of "Where Region = @region" phrase too and not only when i write specifically "Where Region=null"?

Comment: Wouldn't it be (t1.Val1 = t2.Val1 or (t1.Val1 is null and t2.Val1 is null)) ???

Comment: @Gregbert - given `and` has higher precedence, I'm not sure what you think the extra pair of parentheses add.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever simply for readability for those unawares.

Comment: "the option to not have it on is going to be removed in the future" - have you got a reference for this please?

Comment: Caltor - the reference was a prominent notice that used to appear on the documentation page linked to. It appears that notice no longer appears. May be able to find it in Wayback machine

Answer (score 57):

If ANSI_NULLS is set to "ON"  and if we apply = , <> on NULL column value while writing select statement then it will not return any result.

**Example**

```
create table #tempTable (sn int, ename varchar(50))
 
insert into #tempTable
values (1, 'Manoj'), (2, 'Pankaj'), (3, NULL), (4, 'Lokesh'), (5, 'Gopal')
```

**SET ANSI_NULLS ON**

```
select * from #tempTable where ename is NULL -- (1 row(s) affected)
select * from #tempTable where ename = NULL -- (0 row(s) affected)
select * from #tempTable where ename is not NULL -- (4 row(s) affected)
select * from #tempTable where ename <> NULL -- (0 row(s) affected)
```

**SET ANSI_NULLS OFF**

```
select * from #tempTable where ename is NULL -- (1 row(s) affected)
select * from #tempTable where ename = NULL -- (1 row(s) affected)
select * from #tempTable where ename is not NULL -- (4 row(s) affected)
select * from #tempTable where ename <> NULL -- (4 row(s) affected)
```

Reference document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-ansi-nulls-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: +1 for being the ONLY answer that clearly distinguishes between `WHERE X IS NULL` and `WHERE X = NULL`, and how ANSI_NULLS affects the outcome. Despite the over zealous down-voters' attempts, THIS should be the accepted answer!

Comment: +1 for explaining using examples, which will always be clearer and more concise rather than lengthy sentences.

Answer (score 9):

I guess the main thing here is:

**Never** use:

- `@anything = NULL`
- `@anything <> NULL`
- `@anything != null`

because ANSI NULL ON/OFF might change your logic.

**Always** use:

- `@anything IS NULL`
- `@anything IS NOT NULL`

because it will work regardless of ANSI NULL

Answer (score 8):

If `@Region` is not a `null` value (lets say `@Region = 'South'`) it will not return rows where the Region field is null, regardless of the value of ANSI_NULLS.

ANSI_NULLS will only make a difference when the value of `@Region` is `null`, i.e. when your first query essentially becomes the second one.

In that case, ANSI_NULLS ON will not return any rows (because `null = null` will yield an unknown boolean value (a.k.a. `null`)) and ANSI_NULLS OFF will return any rows where the Region field is null (because `null = null` will yield `true`)

Answer (score 3):

SET ANSI_NULLS ON

IT Returns all values including null values in the table

SET ANSI_NULLS off

it Ends when  columns contains null values

Comment: What extra does this answer add to the already stated answers? Be wary of adding new answers to old questions - They should contain expanded explaination on already posted solutions, or provide new insight - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review)

Answer (score 2):

Set ANSI NULLS OFF will make NULL = NULL comparision return true.
EG :

```
        SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
        select * from sys.tables
        where principal_id = Null
```

will return some result as displayed below:
zcwInvoiceDeliveryType  744547  NULL
zcExpenseRptStatusTrack 2099048 NULL
ZCVendorPermissions 2840564 NULL
ZCWOrgLevelClientFee    4322525 NULL

While this query will not return any results:

```
        SET ANSI_NULLS ON 
        select * from sys.tables
        where principal_id = Null
```

Answer (score 1):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-ansi-nulls-transact-sql

When SET ANSI_NULLS is ON, a SELECT statement that uses WHERE column_name = NULL returns zero rows even if there are null values in column_name. A SELECT statement that uses WHERE column_name <> NULL returns zero rows even if there are nonnull values in column_name.

For e.g

```
DECLARE @TempVariable VARCHAR(10)
SET @TempVariable = NULL

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SELECT 'NO ROWS IF SET ANSI_NULLS ON' where    @TempVariable = NULL
-- IF ANSI_NULLS ON , RETURNS ZERO ROWS


SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
SELECT 'THERE WILL BE A ROW IF ANSI_NULLS OFF' where    @TempVariable =NULL
-- IF ANSI_NULLS OFF , THERE WILL BE ROW !
```

Answer (score 1):

**SET ANSI_NULLS ON** will not return any row when you apply `= , <> , !=` in where condition. You need to use  `IS NULL , IS NOT NULL`.

**SET ANSI_NULLS OFF** will always return result when you use `= , <> , != , IS NULL , IS NOT NULL`.