# NULL equality in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I know by default NULL = NULL is not true, so

```
if null = null select 1 else select 2
```

will give you 2

Then you can change that behaviour by

```
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
```

and the result will be 1

My question is why after setting the ANSI_NULLS to OFF, the following SELECT still returns nothing?

```
select * from (select 'a', null) ta (c1, c2), (select 'b', null) tb (c1, c2)
where ta.c2 = tb.c2
```

Comment: This could help you. please have a look!!!
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9766717/in-sql-server-what-does-set-ansi-nulls-on-means

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I really can't answer why it is like that but the behavior is documented.

From [SET ANSI_NULLS (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188048.aspx)

> SET ANSI_NULLS ON affects a comparison only if one of the operands of
>   the comparison is either a variable that is NULL or a literal NULL. If
>   both sides of the comparison are columns or compound expressions, the
>   setting does not affect the comparison.

And also for completeness.

> In a future version of SQL Server, ANSI_NULLS will always be ON and
>   any applications that explicitly set the option to OFF will generate
>   an error. Avoid using this feature in new development work, and plan
>   to modify applications that currently use this feature.

Comment: Thanks. If I am to relate your answer to the behaviour I am experiencing, I shall take "If both sides of the comparison are columns...the setting does not affect the comparison" as the intention of ANSI_NULLS.