# What is 'where 1=1' and 'where null=null' in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table of some columns named as `Students`.

I am using following three queries to `select` rows.

```
 1. select * from Students
 2. select * from Students where 1=1
 3. select * from Students where null=null
```

When I execute first then this returns all rows.

When I execute second then this is also returns all rows.

But when I execute third then this does not return any row.

I have two issues

> 1. What is `1=1` and `null=null` and why are we using these?
> 2. What is difference between first query and second query?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1843451/why-does-null-null-evaluate-to-false-in-sql-server this may be help you to the right direction

Comment: null= null will give  `false` if `ansi_null` is `on` .

Comment: @POHH, I'm just curious, what if ansi_null is off?

Comment: @jarlh http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9766717/in-sql-server-what-does-set-ansi-nulls-on-means this will help you

Comment: @POHH it isn't `false` or `true`. SQL uses three valued logic and it is the third value of `unknown`.

Comment: @Martin Smith yes . the `unknown` will be the result and ultimate output will be `false` the condition will be `false` and will not return any `rows`. thats what i was trying to say. thanx for `correcting`

Comment: The condition will be `unknown` and not return any rows.

Comment: @MartinSmith acccepted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To the questions part about "why" using this:
Since `1=1` always evaluates to `true` and `true` is the neutral element for logical `AND` operation, it is often used for dynamically built queries.

The problem with dynamically built queries that are using multiple `AND` operations added or not to the query on some conditions ist that you've to keep track about it is the `first` condition added or not. (i.e. `SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE AND bla = 'blub'` is not valid; we must suppress the `AND` with the first condition added to the query)

All this can be avoided when we change the queries base to `SELECT * from mytable WHERE 1=1`. Now we can add our `AND` conditions dynamically without considering if it is the first condition added or not. (i.e. `SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE 1=1 AND bla = 'blub'` is valid)

Comment: Along the same lines, I guess the use of the last query is to extend it with OR?

Comment: @VincentvanderWeele Yes, because `false` is the neutral element for logical `OR` operation. But `null=null` is not ideal for various reasons. First of all it is "something special" which can be configured to evaluate to `true` or `false`. Second it is unintuitive that something identical aroung `=` evaluates to `false`. I would prefer using `1=0` over `null=null`in such cases where you need the neutral element for `OR` operation.

Answer (score 2):

if you put `ANSI_NULL off` then it will return `true` . if it is `on` then it will return false

```
set ansi_nulls off

if null = null
    print 'true'
else
    print 'false'


set ansi_nulls ON

if null = null
    print 'true'
else
    print 'false'
```

reference got from [Null=Null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1843451/why-does-null-null-evaluate-to-false-in-sql-server)

@Jarlh if i set `ansi_nulls off`

when you set `ansi_nulls off` it will tell that not to follow `ANSI standerds` for comparing `null` values
then this query will result all rows.

```
set ansi_nulls off

select * from cust_data where null=null
```

Answer (score 2):

- `1=1` is always true
- `null=null` is always false

Usually one uses these constructs, when some code dynamically adds conditions to the `where` clause of a given query.

With `where 1=1` the code can simply add restrictions with `and ...` without having to check whether this is the first restriction.

The same holds true with `where null=null` and `or ...`

**Hint:** this kind of coding comes usually with textual processing of SQL queries (instead of structural processing). Look out for SQL injections when you see such code!

Answer (score 1):

The first query simply returns all rows of the table.

The second query returns only rows that match the `WHERE clause`. Since this where clause is always true, it returns all rows.

The last query again returns only the rows that match the `WHERE clause`. Since this condition is always false, it doesn't return a row at all.

For the last query, you could instead try:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Students WHERE NULL IS NULL
```

The `IS operator` lets you compare `NULL` values, so this query again would return all rows. This is a general rule: never use `=` to check for `NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

This is the simplest logic as 1 = 1 always true and 2 null value are not same when you compare null value.

Where condition is used to filter the data by columns value and if we give the 1 = 1 , its logical filter, then return everything. and when we give 1=2 it gives nothing (just think why).

```
select * from Students
select * from Students where 1=1
```

So your first 2 query is same and that's why it give the same result.

```
select * from Students where null = null
```

Its obviously gives 0 row because both null is difference in terms of compare and the condition is not fullfill.

Try this and find out the logic why it gives as first 2 query.

```
select * from Students where isnull(null,'') = isnull(null ,'')
```

Answer (score 1):

First and Second gives same results.

But 1=1 and null=null are not same. 1=1 is always TRUE but null=null is not.

Null is "unknown" or "does not exist". In that case you cant judge the true of false condition.

If you want to make it true always, then you can use this

```
set ansi_nulls off
```

and check this

```
if null = null
    print 'true'
else
    print 'false'
```

and your third query also works by switching it to OFF.
By default it is set to ON condition 
which always doesn't work