# Can we use '=' for comparing with NULL in sql

Tags: sql

I have table t1 as

```
  EMPNO ENAME      JOB              MGR HIREDATE         SAL       COMM     DEPTNO
------- ---------- --------- ---------- --------- ---------- ---------- ----------
   7369 SMITH      CLERK           7902 17-DEC-80        800                    20
   7499 ALLEN      SALESMAN        7698 20-FEB-81       1600        300         30
   7521 WARD       SALESMAN        7698 22-FEB-81       1250        500         30
   7566 JONES      MANAGER         7839 02-APR-81       2975                    20
   7654 MARTIN     SALESMAN        7698 28-SEP-81       1250       1400         30
   7698 BLAKE      MANAGER         7839 01-MAY-81       2850                    30
   7782 CLARK      MANAGER         7839 09-JUN-81       2450                    10
   7788 SCOTT      ANALYST         7566 19-APR-87       3000                    20
   7839 KING       PRESIDENT            17-NOV-81       5000                    10
   7844 TURNER     SALESMAN        7698 08-SEP-81       1500          0         30
   7876 ADAMS      CLERK           7788 23-MAY-87       1100                    20

  EMPNO ENAME      JOB              MGR HIREDATE         SAL       COMM     DEPTNO
------- ---------- --------- ---------- --------- ---------- ---------- ----------
   7900 JAMES      CLERK           7698 03-DEC-81        950                    30
   7902 FORD       ANALYST         7566 03-DEC-81       3000                    20
   7934 MILLER     CLERK           7782 23-JAN-82       1300                    10
        NULL
        Null
        null
                   VP
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

when I query

```
select * from t1 where ename=null
```

It returns "NO rows selected".
As far as I know we cannot use '=' to compare with null.
So why it is not showing error.

Comment: The answer is NO, . You should get an error.

Comment: @jarlh: the syntax **is** correct - you will not get an error

Comment: As mentioned by the other the `is null` should be enough and your syntax is correct but not used in the right way;However, im curious to no know you set the NULL value . This due to the various casing seen.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, invalid syntax according to ANSI/ISO SQL-2003. Perhaps correct to another older/later version?

Comment: @jarlh: hmm, no DBMS I know of throws a syntax exception for that (would be nice though, I agree)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, some do. (E.g. Mimer SQL.)

Comment: Tag dbms used. (Since this is a product specific issue, ANSI SQL does not accept that syntax.)

Answer (score 8):

> So why it is not showing error?

Because the **syntax** (of the expression) *is* correct.

However - as you already pointed out - even though the syntax of the expression is correct it will never be true

It's similar to writing `where 1=2` - that is "correct" as well, but will never return any rows.

Answer (score 3):

No you can't use = for null values because comparison with `null` values returns 'unknown' result and rows with 'unknown' result aren't included in result set. Use the query instead.

```
select * from t1 where ename is null
```

Comment: That was not the question

Comment: updated my answer to included reason why rows aren't returned

Comment: The question was "why doesn't this generate an error", not why no rows are returned - salam already mentioned that

Answer (score 2):

`NULL` in most flavors of SQL represents a value which is completely unknown.  In this case, when comparing a column against `NULL` it cannot evaluate to `TRUE` because both values are completely unknown.  Logically, comparing "I don't know" against "I don't know" does not evaluate to `TRUE` in SQL thinking.

One real-world analogy for the thinking of comparing `NULL` against `NULL` would be comparing two randomly-drawn playing cards against each other.  We cannot say that there are equal or not equal, because we have never seen them.

Instead of directly comparing for a `NULL` value, try using the `IS NULL` construct:

```
SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE ename IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can use `=` to compare with `null`. The result is *always* going to be `unknown`, of course, but that's a value like any other. It isn't fundamentally different from doing `42 + null`, or using any other operator. Would you really want to get an exception (or a syntax error) any time you're using `null` with some operator? That would kind of defeat the whole purpose of `null`, wouldn't it?

Of course, comparing something with a *literal* `null` is quite likely a mistake, and it might make sense for you to get a warning. But that would also mean that a literal should behave differently from a "real" value - and you really don't want that.

This is mostly analogous to how `NaN` works in floats. Any operation that involves a `NaN` results in `NaN` - except for `isNaN`, which is analogous to `is null` in SQL.

Answer (score 1):

There is no error message because there is no error.

You can compare for equality to NULL. It just always returns UNKKNOWN/NULL. If you want to know whether ename is NULL then write `ename IS NULL`.

A SELECT can return no rows. A query just returns all the rows that are like what you asked. If none of them are like that then none are returned.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `IS NULL` instead of `=` to make this work.

```
SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE ename IS NULL
```

If you are using SQL Server, `SET ANSI NULL OFF`.
Set ANSI NULLS OFF will make NULL = NULL comparision return true

Also check  this one **[In SQL Server, what does “SET ANSI_NULLS ON” mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9766717/in-sql-server-what-does-set-ansi-nulls-on-mean)**

> When you compare two NULL expressions, the result depends on the ANSI_NULLS setting:
>
> If ANSI_NULLS is set to ON, the result is NULL, following the ANSI convention that a NULL (or unknown) value is not equal to another NULL or unknown value.
>
> If ANSI_NULLS is set to OFF, the result of NULL compared to NULL is TRUE.
>
> Comparing NULL to a non-NULL value always results in FALSE2.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose because Null means nothing, you are looking for some unknown value and get nothing.
As written in T-SQL help:

> To determine whether an expression is NULL, use IS NULL or IS NOT NULL
>   instead of comparison operators (such as = or !=). Comparison
>   operators return UNKNOWN when either or both arguments are NULL.

So I think, because comparison operators return UNKNOWN it is not the error it is just behauviour of the SQL server.