# SET ANSI_NULL is ON but NULL rows are still being returned

Tags: sql, ansi-nulls

I have the following table with SET ANSI_NULL set to ON

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblStandard5columnCustomerDetails]
(
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [FName] [varchar](60) NULL,
    [Address] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [PhoneNumber] [varchar](11) NULL,
    [LName] [varchar](60) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

And inserted the following one record:

```
Insert Into [dbo].[tblStandard5columnCustomerDetails] 
VALUES
(
1,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL
);
```

According to Microsoft article I should not be returning any rows when using Select statement with `WHERE column_name = NULL`

> When SET ANSI_NULLS is ON, a SELECT statement that uses WHERE
>   column_name = NULL returns zero rows even if there are null values in
>   column_name. A SELECT statement that uses WHERE column_name <> NULL
>   returns zero rows even if there are nonnull values in column_name.

But when is execute this query

```
select FNAME From [dbo].[tblStandard5columnCustomerDetails] WHERE FName IS NULL
```

I'm returning one row with a value of NULL

Why?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9766717/in-sql-server-what-does-set-ansi-nulls-on-mean?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically answered your own question.

With "SET ANSI_NULLS ON":

- the "relational operators" `+, <, >, <=, >=` will never evaluate to "true" or "false" if one of the operands is null.
- `IS NULL`, on the other hand, will *always* evaluate to "true" (if null), or "false" (if not null).

Look here for more details:

- [In SQL Server, what does "SET ANSI_NULLS ON" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9766717/in-sql-server-what-does-set-ansi-nulls-on-mean)
- http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/378958/meaning-of-SET-ANSI-NULLS-ON
- http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/sqlstudies/2014/07/28/what-is-ansi_nulls-and-why-will-i-be-glad-when-it-finally-goes-away/

Comment: To have no NULL rows being returned with ANSI_NULL set to ON I need to use the Equals operator (= NULL), and not IS NULL. Thanks for the reference to the other post. It clarified a lot.