# Difference between "IS NOT NULL" and "NOT (field = NULL)" in these 2 queries

Tags: mysql, sql

What is the difference between the following 2 queries?

```
DELETE FROM experience WHERE end IS NOT NULL;
```

And

```
DELETE FROM experience WHERE NOT( end=NULL);
```

First query was accepted as a correct answer but second was not.

Comment: It also depends on how the null value is treated.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9766717/in-sql-server-what-does-set-ansi-nulls-on-mean

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NULL values are treated differently from other values.

NULL is used as a placeholder for unknown or inapplicable values.
It is not possible to test for NULL values with comparison operators, such as =, <, or <>

You will have to use the IS NULL and IS NOT NULL operators instead.

Please refer below link for more details.

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_null_values.asp

Answer (score 8):

NULLs are a bit weird. A NULL is *never* equal to *anything **including another NULL.*** Further, any boolean operation against a NULL returns NULL.

The expression `end IS NOT NULL` will evaluate **`false`** if `end` is NULL, and **`true`** if `end` is not NULL.

The expression `NOT( end=NULL)` will actually always evaluate to NULL because `(end = NULL)` equals NULL and `NOT (NULL)` also equals NULL. More to the point in a WHERE clause, it will *never* evaluate **`true`**.

Answer (score 1):

Comparing a variable to null (i.e.  field = NULL) is the same as assigning an unknown value to "field."  IS NOT NULL checks to see if the field is null.  The second NOT (end=NULL) is assigning a value of "Unknown" to field and then NOTing the result.  You should not assign a variable to an unknown value.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use "NOT" alone. It should be followed by "IS". So if you want the second query to work then use - DELETE FROM experience WHERE IS NOT( end=NULL);

Answer (score 1):

An expression with `NULL` in it can never be evaluated as true except if combined with `IS` (but see further). As stated in the [MySql docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/working-with-null.html):

> You cannot use arithmetic comparison operators such as `=`, `<`, or `<>` to test for `NULL`.
>
> Because the result of any arithmetic comparison with `NULL` is also `NULL`, you cannot obtain any meaningful results from such comparisons.

#### Exceptions to the Rule

Not all expressions with `NULL` as argument evaluate to `NULL`. Apart from `NULL IS NULL`, also the following will yield a truthy value:

```
NULL <=> NULL,
COALESCE(NULL, true),
IFNULL(NULL, true),
ISNULL(NULL),
1 IN (1, NULL),
INTERVAL(1, 0, 2, NULL)
CASE 1 WHEN 1 THEN TRUE WHEN NULL THEN false END
```

The reason that the last three do not yield `NULL` is that these expressions perform some form of [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation). So if during the evaluation from left-to-right the outcome is clear, the rest of the expression (including the `NULL`) is not evaluated.

But all of the following will be `NULL`:

```
NULL = NULL
CASE NULL WHEN NULL THEN TRUE END,
'test' || NULL,
GREATEST(1, NULL),
1 NOT IN (2, NULL)
```

Note how in the last two expressions, short-circuiting is not a possibility: all arguments must be evaluated, at least until a `NULL` is found.

#### `ANSI_NULLS` Setting

There is an [`ANSI_NULLS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188048.aspx) setting that influences the above behaviour when set to `OFF`. It is `ON` by default, and it should in fact not be altered. As stated in the docs:

> **Important**
>
> In a future version of SQL Server, `ANSI_NULLS` will always be `ON` and any applications that explicitly set the option to `OFF` will generate an error. Avoid using this feature in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use this feature.

So, I don't believe it is worth discussing this setting further: don't touch it.