# How to check a record for all fields to not be NULL or Empty?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a record from a MySQL Database that needs to be validated to see if all the fields have a value or post some alert.

Is the best way to put all the field values into an array and then check the SUM where NOT NULL or Empty to see if it matches the qty of selected fields?

EXAMPLE:
$result = | Value  |  NULL  |  NULL |  Value  |  EMPTY  |

In this example the Record has values from 5 Fields and 2 of those Fields are not Null or Empty

I need Validate to see when all 5 Fields have some value

Comment: Do you still want to retrieve such records from the database, or do you prefer the query to be modified so that such cases are never returned in the result set?

Comment: Since it is a validation in purpose, either will work. I'm trying to learn what options exist to better my understanding and skillset.

If TotalRows==0 could be used if the recordset is empty (MySQL does the work polling for values in all selected fields)

Comment: What data types do you columns have?

Comment: Some are Decimal (4,2) and others are Date.
Leaning towards a reverse IN   such as WHERE NOT NULL IN (column1, column2, column3) but not sure how to search for NOT NULL or EMPTY in such a query.

Comment: SQL Fiddle that does not work by may be in the right direction: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7f995/6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`GREATEST`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest) (or [`LEAST`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_least)):

```
SELECT * 
FROM   table1 
WHERE  GREATEST(col1, col2, col3, col4) IS NOT NULL
```

See [SQL fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/efc959/1)

The idea is that `GREATEST` needs to check all of the arguments, and because expressions with `NULL` will return `NULL` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36076461/difference-between-is-not-null-and-not-field-null-in-these-2-queries/36096230#36096230) for exceptions to that rule), `GREATEST` will return `NULL` if any of its arguments is `NULL`.

The above will filter the records that meat the condition, i.e. that do no have `NULL` values. With the same idea you could something that does not filter, but adds the information on whether it has a `NULL` or not:

```
SELECT *, 
       CASE WHEN GREATEST(col1, col2, col3, col4) IS NULL 
           THEN 0 
           ELSE 1
       END AS is_OK
FROM   table1
```

Now you will have an extra column in the result with either 0 or 1. It indicates whether your columns are all not `NULL`.

Comment: The only problem is I already know the specific Record. So it is not the selection of the least or greatest Record but rather knowing if all the fields have values or not.

Comment: But you can use this. You'd specify the *id* condition in the `WHERE` clause and then see if you get any result. If so, it means the record does not contain `NULL` values. If not, it means it does. See my added paragraph on how you could otherwise use `GREATEST`.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it directly in the mysql query

```
WHERE COALESCE('some_field', '') = ''
```

this will return every record, where some_field is an empty string or null

more about [COALESCE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) function