# What is the difference between NOT condition and NOT() in Oracle and MS SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

Recently I happened to come across not () in Sql Server and Oracle. Tried different examples comparing NOT condition and not() with different operators such as LIKE, IN etc. I don't see any difference in terms of the resultset and record counts, but wants to confirm with community if both of these are doing the same or any caveat?

Example Queries

```
select count(*) from Emp where country not in ('ENGLAND UK', 'HAITI', 'IRELAND') 
select count(*) from Emp where not(country  in ('ENGLAND UK', 'HAITI', 'IRELAND'))
```

Comment: In SQL Server, you can get the server to generate execution plans. You could then compare the execution plans for these two queries and see that they're identical. There is similar functionality in Oracle, under a different name.

Comment: SQL 2014 and 2016: with a literal argument list in the `IN()` clause, no difference in SQL execution plans. if a PK column is involved, it will be a clustered index seek, otherwise a clustered index scan. with a subquery and optimal keys, it will be two scans and a left anti semi join, no difference wherever the `NOT` operator is placed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both placements of the `NOT` keyword are logically equivalent and give the same results. `NOT` before a bracketed expression inverts the result of that expression, but that is conventional boolean logic and not specific to SQL.

In T-SQL, execution plans are the same in SQL Server 2014 and SQL Server 2016 for your examples (assumption: the table has a primary key and `country` is not indexed).

There is one caveat especially with the examples you gave: The `IN` operator behaves differently than one might expect, when it has `NULL` values in its argument. For Oracle, [see here](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::no::p11_question_id:442029737684);

for T-SQL, consider this:

```
select 1 where 'A' in (null)
```

This will not return a row. Which appears trivial, but:

```
select 1 where 'A' not in (null)
```

This statement will not return a row eiher. Now we could argue, if we logically invert the expression from the first statement like this, it definitely should return a row:

```
select 1 where not ('A' in (null))
```

But it does not, because `IN (NULL)` evaluates to [neither true nor false](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9766756/1132334).

Answer (score 4):

Difference will be there when you have another condition with `AND/OR`. It inverts the `AND` to `OR` and `OR` to `AND`

```
select 1 where not(1 = 1 or 1 <> 1 )
```

will be same as

```
select 1 where (1 <> 1 and 1 = 1 )
```

and

```
select 1 where not(1 = 1 and 1 <> 1 )
```

will be same as

```
select 1 where (1 <> 1 or 1 = 1 )
```

and

```
select 1 where not(1 = 1) or 1 = 1
```

will not be same as

```
select 1 where not(1 = 1 or 1 = 1 )
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case, no real difference

Look at this though:

```
where x1 not in ('a','b','c') 
and x2 not in ('x','y','z')
```

This can be written as

```
where not (x1 in ('a','b','c')
           or x2 in ('x','y','z'))
```

When writing queries, sometimes I use `or` when I'm identifying what I want to exclude. It's easier to just use `not()` than to rewrite the `or` to `and ... not ...`