# is there any difference between: "not variable is null" and "variable is not null"?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm a newbie in SQL and I'm wondering if there is any difference between:

```
not variable is null
```

and

```
variable is not null
```

Comment: **ZERO** difference

Comment: Is the same as `! a==b` and `a!=b` but I would prefer the last one. Wouldn't you?

Comment: You have just single condition or any other condition ?

Comment: Only difference is the readability of the code.

Comment: I'm just trying to understand one script and this kind of syntax i've never seen before. Thanks for the reply. I would prefer the second one because its visually more understandable

Comment: The difference is that `not variable is null` is harder to read and reason about for the developer, while `variable is not null` sounds natural.

Comment: Check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41504329/what-is-the-difference-between-not-condition-and-not-in-oracle-and-ms-sql-serv/41504527#41504527

Comment: As Joda would say: Difference there is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Practically there is NO Difference in both terms. Both of them refers to **Nullability of the Variable**.

If there is any difference then it's simplicity in the reading.