# Why doesn't the equivalence check @x = null work in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

To be clear I understand why it technically doesn't work as it's following the behavior defined in the ANSI spec. But what I don't understand is why this is a desirable behavior. Further, the existence of `IS NULL`, to me at least, seems like a kludge to fix the fact that `@x = null` is always false.

So why would you want to design a language such that checking if anything equals null fails and forcing users to use `IS NULL` instead? Besides legacy compatibility what would be a scenario where checking if a field or parameter = null would lead to ambiguous or erroneous results?

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9766717/in-sql-server-what-does-set-ansi-nulls-on-mean and Microsoft documentation about [ANSI_NULLS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-ansi-nulls-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: NULL is not treated as a value you can not do an = or != on it.  https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-null-values.htm

Comment: SQL uses three valued logic. It is not always false. It is `unknown`

Comment: It can work and not work depending on settings

Comment: @AlexYu Good to know, but SET ANSI_NULLS is being deprecated. Since it's going to be always ON going forward, the question still remains why this is desirable.

Comment: @MartinSmith I've read this, but I still don't understand why this is a desirable design choice. I have never found the inability to check if something is equal to NULL without IS NULL useful and in fact makes my WHERE clauses cumbersome.

Comment: @Legion You're mistaken:  ["In a future version of SQL Server, ANSI_NULLS will be ON and any applications that explicitly set the option to OFF **will** generate an error"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-ansi-nulls-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: @AlexYu I'm not sure how I'm mistaken. That's the sentence I'm referring to. I consider it being always on and trying to set it to off throwing an error to be de facto deprecated, ie. you can't use it.

Comment: @Legion Ah, I see. It's just a question of terminology. In practice deprecation of such features usually postponed from version to version and even than they are rarely goes into complete inexistence.

Comment: Ask the ANSI standards committee.

Comment: Its because NULL isnt a value. It means unknown, which put another way means "could be anything". So if I have one car that is red, but the colour hasn't been recorded, and another that is blue but also hasn't been recorded, then saying car1.colour=car2.colour would be incorrect.

Comment: @TomC I see what you're saying but I'd be inclined to say car1.color = car2.color if they are both unknown. Once the color is recorded for one or the other car then car1.color <> car2.color.