# What does <> (angle brackets) mean in MS-SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

In My Query one place some other developer using `<> (angle brackets)` What does it mean ?

```
sb.append(" AND nvl(VoidFlag, 'N') <> 'Y' ");
```

Comment: It means "not equal" and is the standard SQL operator for that.

Comment: It is the same as `!=`

Comment: The key to being a good developer: Learning to read documentation. [Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188074.aspx)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Not equal <> != operator in T-SQL on NULL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5658457/not-equal-operator-in-t-sql-on-null)

Comment: `nvl` is not a SQL Server function.

Answer (score 27):

<> operator means not equal to in MS SQL.

It compares two expressions (a comparison operator). When you compare nonnull expressions, the result is TRUE if the left operand is not equal to the right operand; otherwise, the result is FALSE. If either or both operands are NULL, see the topic SET ANSI_NULLS (Transact-SQL).

See here : [Not Equal To](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176020.aspx)

Also check :

1) [Not equal <> != operator on NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5658457/not-equal-operator-in-t-sql-on-null)
2) [Testing for inequality in T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7884/testing-for-inequality-in-t-sql)